# Changing language of HTML form in code behind

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, forms

On custom sharepoint ASPX page, I have a small HTML form with 3 input types of text and a submit button. I want to know is there any way to change the language of whole the form in codebehind? i want to switch between Swedish and English languages. any useful suggestion how can i do this ?

Comment: will the language change on button click or according to browser culture it will change.

Comment: in mypage.aspx i have two anchor tags <a href="mypage.aspx">Swedish</a><a href="mypage.aspx">English</a>. Now in code behind of mypage.aspx, under its page load event, i want to change the language of form. I am Calling the same page again

Comment: you can use database to keep the text in all the controls of the page. On load change the text from the database. or you can use resource file. an example is http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasham/resource-files-in-Asp-Net-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Localization using resources.  [Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  that way you take the text out of the page and load it based on the language(s) you are supporting.  You end up creating a resource file for each language you want to support.

If you are working in a SharePoint Web Part that needs to support different languages then see if [Walkthrough: Localizing a Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491702%28v=office.14%29.aspx) would be of assistance to you.

Comment: I have already created Resources file (.resx) each for Swedish and English language. I am using my own custom master page. And i am using application page on which i have created small HTML form. Now under anchor tags like <a href="somepage.aspx">Swedish</a>, how i access resource file ?

Comment: Did you check the section on explicit localization under the "Using Resources for Localization" article.  It looks like that might explains how to do what you are attempting.